# Why does error handler trigger with no error?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am running one line of code to open a PDF when a button is clicked. I put an error handler on there in case the file doesn't exist. The problem is that the code works and the file is opened but the error handler still runs.

When I disable the error handling code it runs fine and VB doesn't generate an error. I even tried using `Err.Description` for the message box and it just pops up with nothing displayed. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenPDF_Click()

On Error GoTo Errorhandler
 Application.FollowHyperlink "E:\groups\folder\folder2\" & Dir("E:\groups\folder\folder2\*" & Me.txtInvNum & "*")

Errorhandler:
        MsgBox "Unable to locate the file. I'm sorry this has happened.", vbOKOnly
  Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Since the PDF opens with no problem I would expect there to be no error. It's also really puzzling that there is no error when run without the error handler. Does anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: Move the `Exit Sub` before the `Errorhandler:` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `Errorhandler` is merely a [line label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#line-label), with the `On Error` statement redirecting evaluation to this label in the event of an error.

As such, consider that VBA does not distinguish between the line label used for the purpose of an error handler, or any other line label used in conjunction with any other `GoTo` statement, or a line label which is not referenced at all.

In the absence of an error, your code is equivalent to:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenPDF_Click()
    Application.FollowHyperlink "E:\groups\folder\folder2\" & Dir("E:\groups\folder\folder2\*" & Me.txtInvNum & "*")

Errorhandler:
    MsgBox "Unable to locate the file. I'm sorry this has happened.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Here, VBA will dutifully execute the `FollowHyperlink` method, followed by the `MsgBox` function, and then finally the `Exit Sub` statement.

To avoid the error handler being evaluated every time, a typical implementation of an error handler will include an additional label signifying a clean exit prior to the error handler label, e.g.:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenPDF_Click()
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler
    Application.FollowHyperlink "E:\groups\folder\folder2\" & Dir("E:\groups\folder\folder2\*" & Me.txtInvNum & "*")

ExitSub:
    Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
    MsgBox "Unable to locate the file. I'm sorry this has happened.", vbOKOnly
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

This means that in normal circumstances, the `Exit Sub` statement will be reached before evaluation of the code following the `Errorhandler` label.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't realize the specifics of using labels in this way. It works fine now.